# Setting up Intellij and AWS environment to work with DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Lately I started to grow interest in AWS. Since I work with IntelliJ in my work place I would love it if I could keep on using it at home as well.

Which leads me to my question - I installed IntelliJ and I would like to know what else should I install and configure in order to get my environment running.
I have seen the following in a few posts regarding other topics -

[AWS Manager](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4558?pr=)

[SDK For Java](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/)

Am I missing anything? Am I installing something un-needed?
Any configuration I should do? Any other tips you would like to share with me?

Thanks!

Comment: Exactly what AWS tasks do you want to perform from within IntelliJ? I use IntelliJ and AWS, but I don't use any AWS plugins or interact with AWS from within IntelliJ in any way as I don't see the need. You definitely don't *need* to integrate your IDE with your IaaS platform.

Comment: For starters, I'd like to create or use some kind of API to store and retrieve data from DynamoDB.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to include the AWS SDK libraries in your project.

Comment: Ok, so I'm doing so, and I guess it is kind of a noobish question, but in - http://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/java/ they say "create a credentials file" but they don't say what the name of the file is...

Comment: It says specifically at that link what the filename is: `~/.aws/credentials` or `C:\Users\USER_NAME\.aws\credentials` for Windows users.

Comment: You can use AWS-CLI, even I use IntelliJ n Eclipse, but I find AWS-CLI very useful when it comes to play with AWS services. Give it a try: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/

Comment: Thanks mbaird, I knew I was looking at it wrong some how. (feels like a noob). kosmix I will look for it soon, thanks as well.

Comment: This should be useful while creating credentials.. If you wanted to create a folder name ".aws" with DOT a front like ".aws" then while naming the folder use a dot at the end too ".aws... It is a valid hidden folder.

Comment: Thought this might interest you. A month earlier I started with similar such doubts and enthusiasm. This link might help you : http://techmonies.com/index.php/2017/01/05/aws-java-sdk-and-maven-setup/. I've covered other articles related to AWS/ dynamoDB/ intelliJ.  Disclaimer : I am new to AWS and learning it by doing quite hands on !

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this document here - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html

The correct name for the secret key variable is AWS_SECRET_KEY.

Using CLI limits you to work with a single Amazon account. And if that is not the case with you, you should not use CLI.

Options 1 and 2 allows to set these credentials per project with different AWS accounts outside the project codebase. Go for those options instead.